# Headers not being recognised

Tags: c++, include, makefile

#### The Background

I have the following source code

```
#include <libubuntuone-1.0/u1-music-store.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/libsyncdaemon.h>

static void
get_credentials (U1MusicStore *music_store,
                                 gchar **oauth_consumer_token,
                                 gchar **oauth_consumer_secret,
                                 gchar **oauth_token,
                                 gchar **oauth_token_secret)
{
    SyncdaemonCredentials *credentials;
    *oauth_consumer_token = *oauth_consumer_secret = *oauth_token = *oauth_token_secret = NULL;

    *oauth_consumer_token = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_consumer_key (credentials));
    *oauth_consumer_secret = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_consumer_secret (credentials));
    *oauth_token = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_token (credentials));
    *oauth_consumer_secret = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_token_secret (credentials));
}

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

and I am compiling it with the following makefile

```
main: main.o
    g++ main.o -o main

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

I need to include the `pkg-config` option since the `u1-music-store.h` header tried to included `gtk/gtk.h`, but the compiler isn't able to find it on it's own.

`libsyncdaemon.h` is a meta-header whose only purpose is to include a larger list of headers, which can be seen below

```
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-authentication.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-config-interface.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-credentials.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-daemon.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-events-interface.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-file-info.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-filesystem-interface.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-folder-info.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-folders-interface.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-interface.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-publicfiles-interface.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-share-info.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-status-info.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-status-interface.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-transfer-info.h>
```

#### My problem

Whenever I try to compile my code, I get the following error:

```
main.o: In function `get_credentials(_U1MusicStore*, char**, char**, char**, char**)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `syncdaemon_credentials_get_consumer_key'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `g_strdup'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `syncdaemon_credentials_get_consumer_secret'
main.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `g_strdup'
main.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `syncdaemon_credentials_get_token'
main.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `g_strdup'
main.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `syncdaemon_credentials_get_token_secret'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `g_strdup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error
```

Using `grep`, I've tracked down the four `syncdaemon_credentials_get_*` functions to `syncdaemon-credentials.h`, which I would expect the compiler to be able to find since it's listed in `libsyncdaemon.h`, but for some reason that's not happening. I'm assuming it's for the reason that `u1-music-store.h` was unable to find `gtk/gtk.h` that compelled me to use the `pkg-config` option in my makefile, but I'm having trouble understanding why this is even the case to begin with. If the file's `#included`, I would expect it to be included by the compiler.

Using `grep` again I was able to track down `g_strdup` to a number of headers, but I also discovered that when I replaced by makefile with the single command

```
g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

I can eliminate the `g_strdup` warning, and I'm just left with the function errors.

#### My question

There are two things I'm looking to know here:

1. What should my makefile look like in order to solve my specific problem
2. What is the general solution to my problem? I'm guessing it's something to do with daisy-chaining `#include` directives together, and having to use `pkg-config` to fix that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: As Ignacio's answer shows, the title of this question misstates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to link against libsyncdaemon.so. Get the appropriate arguments from `pkg-config ... libsyncdaemon-1.0`.
2. You need to link against libraries that export the required symbols. If there is a .pc file then you can use it to get the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

"Unresolved external symbol" (MSVC) and "undefined reference to" (GCC) mean that the compiler found the *declarations* but the linker couldn't find the *definitions*.
This either means that you forgot to compile and/or link against a `.cpp` or that you forgot to link against an external library (`.lib (Windows)` / `.a (Unix/Linux)`) or object file (`.o`) which contains said definitions.